# What are the advantages of 2 HW partition

Tags: linux, memory, embedded-linux, sd-card

I have a need to store 2 versions of linux image in eMMC. 
One would be Golden image and other would be Backup image.
I plan to store them in General Purpose (GP) partition configured in SLC mode.

**Method 1**

I can either store both the versions in same HW partion (GP partition in SLC mode) or

**Method 2**

Can create 2 GP partitions (both configured in SLC mode) and store one linux version in each GP partition.

Would like to understand benefits of Method 2 over Method 1. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure that your eMMC chips allow to changing SLC/MLC modes after initial configuration? (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=175217 **The eMMC can be programmed once in its lifetime with enhanced capabilities** *This is done at the same time as the eMMC is partitioned by the manufacturer of the device that contains the eMMC.*) With SLC mode you will have only half of size. And with MLC mode with full size there are less P/E cycles allowed (guaranteed).

Comment: Agree. pSLC or MLC can be configured only once initially. My doubt is as part of initial setup. What benefits does having 2 GP partitions(and storing each linux image in separate GP partition) has against 1 GP partition (and storing both linux copies there) ?

Comment: With larger SLC part you have less usable size of the eMMC. MLC is good for data without very active writing. If your backup is used by restoring over the other partition, you need no SLC for it. Both your methods lists both images in SLC mode....